# Use auxiliary table to define values for another table's column

Tags: sql, t-sql, case

I am working with a table that currently uses multiple CASE expressions to define the behavior of one of the columns, i.e.:

```
SELECT 
  Employee
  ,Company
  ,Department
  ,Area
  ,Flag = CASE 
    WHEN Company = 'Amazon' and Department in ('IT', 'HR')
    THEN 0
    WHEN Department = 'Legal'
    THEN 1
    WHEN Area = 'Cloud'
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END
FROM Table1
```

Which would result in something like the following dummy data:

| Employee | Company | Department | Area | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cindy | Amazon | IT | Support | 0 |
| Jack | Amazon | HR | Support | 0 |
| Bob | Microsoft | Legal | Contracts | 1 |
| Joe | Amazon | Legal | Research | 1 |
| Lauren | Google | IT | Cloud | 1 |
| Jane | Apple | UX | Research | 0 |

I am trying to simplify the `Flag` expression by using an auxiliary `Mappings` table that has the following structure, in order to get the value for the Flag column:

| Company | Department | Area | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Amazon | IT | NULL | 0 |
| Amazon | HR | NULL | 0 |
| NULL | Legal | NULL | 1 |
| NULL | NULL | Cloud | 1 |

The `NULL` values mean the column could take any value. Is it possible to achieve this without falling into multiple `CASE` statements?

Comment: Presumably this is an `update` - include the full query, not a fragment - the case expression should return a scalar value.

Comment: @Stu Thanks for the comment, edited and polished it a little bit to make it more clear. It is actually used as a CTE for an INSERT later on.

Comment: So why can't you outer-join to your mapping table and put the required criteria as a join condition?

Comment: What is the expected value when none of the conditions match? Your example `case` defaults to `0`, but it isn't clear whether a failure to match a `Mappings` table row should return `0`, `null` or something more interesting. Aside: As the description for the `case` tag says, it's an _expression_ not a _statement_.

Comment: @Stu I have used an ```OUTER JOIN``` resulting in all the values from the ```Original``` table + the values from the ```Mappings``` table (as expected), I am expecting the ```Original``` table with the Flag column being populated with the CASE logic.

Comment: @HABO When none of the conditions are matched (meaning the case when the values are other than the ones on the ```Mappings``` table) I expect the ```ELSE``` part of the ```CASE``` expression, for example, if I where to have a record that has ```C1Value2``` for ```Column1```, ```C2Value4``` for ```Column2```, and ```C3Value2``` for ```Column3```, I would expect to return the ```ELSE``` for the ```Flag``` column (which would be ```0```). Feel free to think the 1's and 0's from the Flag as strings or whatever.

Comment: sample data for `Table1` please

Comment: Your comment to Stu re: the `OUTER JOIN` makes it sound like you tried `select * from ...;` rather than `select Original.*, Coalesce( Mappings.Flag, 0 ) as Flag from ...;`.

Comment: @dougp changed dummy data to look like a real example.
@HABO I used ```ISNULL``` instead of ```COALESCE```, will test and upvote if I succeed, thanks a lot!

Comment: I think with the level of complexity you have the `CASE` statement will work better.  Trying to join to something with those conditions will likely generate duplicate or incorrect rows.